# highstock shows wrong dates in selectorRange buttons

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vEh9.png)i get dates from server and convert all date to timestamp as required highcharts. But, rangeSelector buttons show wrong date. For, example if i have dateBegin = 02/07/2017, and dateEnd 09/07/2017, highstock dateRange shows wrong date like as 01/07/2017 - 08/07/2017. It seems that highstock show always date - 1 day. How can i fix it?

this is my init of config
  onInitConfig = ({ series, periodId, height }) => {
    const { onSelectRange } = this.props

```
moment.locale('ru', localization)

const heightChart = `${ height }px`

const config = {
  chart: {
    height: heightChart,
    events: {
      redraw: function(event) {
        const currentDateBegin =  Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.rangeSelector.minInput.HCTime)
        const currentDateEnd = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.rangeSelector.maxInput.HCTime)
        onSelectRange && onSelectRange({ currentDateBegin, currentDateEnd })
      }
    }
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
      type: 'week',
      count: '1',
      text: 'н'
    },{
      type: 'month',
      count: 1,
      text: 'м',
    },{
      type: 'month',
      count: 3,
      text: 'кв'
    }, {
      type: 'month',
      count: '6',
      text: 'пг'
    },{
      type: 'year',
      count: 1,
      text: 'г'
    }],
    buttonSpacing: 2,
    selected: periodId - 1,
    inputDateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y',
    labelStyle: {
      fontFamily: 'HelveticaLight',
      fontSize: '14px',
    }
  },
  title: {
    align: 'left',
    text: '',
  },
  navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  },
  navigator: {
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        formatter: function () {
          return moment(this.value).format('DD MMMM')
        },
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'HelveticaLight',
          fontSize: '14px',
        }
      }
    },
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      formatter: function () {
        return moment(this.value).format('DD MMMM')
      },
      style: {
        fontFamily: 'HelveticaLight',
        fontSize: '14px',
      }
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      compare: 'percent',
      showInNavigator: true
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
    valueDecimals: 2,
    split: true
  },
  series: series
}

return config
```

}

this is my input

```
order.map((id) => {
      const { dateBegin, dateEnd, valueAmount, valueCount, valueQuantity, valueCountCheck, valueCountCustomers } = data[id] || {}
      const dateTimeBegin = moment(dateBegin, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate().getTime()
      const dateTimeEnd = moment(dateBegin, 'DD.MM.YYYY').toDate().getTime()

      _.merge( dataCheckCount, { [id]: { id, x: dateTimeBegin, y: valueCount } })
      _.merge( dataCheckCount, { [id + 1]: { id: id + 1, x: dateTimeEnd, y: valueCount } })
}
```

Comment: Please share your code and the data you input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in timezoneOffset. I add next code to global setOptions and the problem is fixed.

`global: {
    useUTC: false,
  },`